# Unable to delete specific columns with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was moving along nicely with my very first coding project but have hit a wall. I'm trying to automate formatting a sheet used for food costing. The first thing I do after importing data to the sheet is delete two columns (A and C) that aren't needed. This is the part of the code that is not working. It only deletes column C. If take out deleteColumn(3), it still deletes C. I've tried searching but what I've read makes me think I had it right (which of course I don't). The rest of the code seems to go fine though I'm sure it could be simplified.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  sheet.deleteColumn(1); //delete column A, ends up deleting C when I run this by itself
  sheet.deleteColumn(3); //delete column C

  var column = sheet.getRange("B2:B"); 
  column.setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)"); //Format B(formerly D) as currency

  var column = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
  column.setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)"); //Format C as currency

  var column = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
  column.setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00;$(#,##0.00)"); //Format D as currency

  sheet.getRange('E2').setFormula('=DIVIDE(B2,D2)'); //Divide ingredient cost by selling price
  sheet.getRange('E2').copyTo(sheet.getRange('E3:E18')); //Copy to all items
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `sheet.deleteColumn(1)` is supposed to delete the 3rd column. But there is another issue (maybe even the root of your issue) in the way your code is structured.

Deleting Rows and Columns in google sheets will immediately make everything else fill up the now "empty" space. So if you delete row 3 for example: The row that has previoulsy been row 4 is now row 3 and so on.

This means in deleting column A first you cause everything to shift, meaning the column that was originally column C is now column B (since everything shiftet one column to the left) - you now delete column C (which is not the column that was column C when you started)

In order to prevent the immediate shifting of rows and columns to screw up your deleting operation, you should start deleting from the biggest to the smallest number. So for example if you want to delete column 1, 3 and 7 you should delete them in the order 7 -> 3 -> 1.

This way you avoid shifting columns that will be deleted in the future. (same for rows)

Comment: Thank you. Going in that order (high to low) helps make things a lot clearer.